# Screenshot script can't save the .png image with the actual date

Tags: python, timer, screenshot

I'm writing a python script to screenshot every 30 seconds and save the output image with the actual date.

The problem is that the script is saving each image with each letter of the `time.ctime()` output (`Tue Jan  3 01:30:53 2017`):

`T.png
 u.png
 e.png
 ...`

How can i save each image output with the actual complete date ?

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import time

max_prints = 10
counter = 0

timer = time.ctime()

while counter < max_prints:
    for mark in timer:
        im=ImageGrab.grab()
        #im.show()
        im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(10,10,500,500))
        #im.show()
        ImageGrab.grab_to_file(str(mark) + ".png")
        time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: `for mark in timer` iterates across each letter in the string `timer`

Answer (score 0):

This loop may help:

```
while counter < max_prints:
    im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(10, 10, 500, 500))
    filename = str(dt.datetime.now()).replace(' ', 'T').split('.')[0] + ".png"
    ImageGrab.grab_to_file(filename)
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with something like this ?

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import time

max_prints = 10
counter = 0

while counter < max_prints:
    im=ImageGrab.grab()
    #im.show()
    im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(10,10,500,500))
    #im.show()
    timer = time.ctime()
    ImageGrab.grab_to_file(timer + ".png")
    time.sleep(30)
    counter += 1
```

If you want to you could have filenames that will be easier to handle afterward by changing these lines:

```
    timer = time.ctime()
    ImageGrab.grab_to_file(timer + ".png")
```

To this:

```
    timer = time.ctime()
    timestamp = timer.replace(' ', '_')
    timestamp = timestamp.replace(':', '_')
    filename = "{}.png".format(timestamp)
    ImageGrab.grab_to_file(filename)
```

But it depends on how you want your files to be named.